# How to convert column of DataFrame with n values to n binary columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am prety sure that there is a pandas function to do so but I could not find it when I was looking at the documentation and googled it. Maybe you can help me.
Here is what I want to do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': ['val1','val2','val3'],
        'col2': ['feat1','feat1','feat2']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

>    col1   col2
> 0  val1  feat1
> 1  val2  feat1
> 2  val3  feat2
```

and I want to have the dataframe with this shape:

```
>    col1  feat1  feat2
> 0  val1      1      0
> 1  val2      1      0
> 2  val3      0      1
```

Best P

Comment: You need `.get_dummies()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('col1'), prefix='', prefix_sep=''))
```

Prints:

```
      feat1  feat2
col1              
val1      1      0
val2      1      0
val3      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)
```